# How can I restart start menu?

Tags: windows-10

All of a sudden my start menu stopped working: when I press windows button, Win+tab, left or right click on windows icon in the taskbar just nothing happens.

Alt+tab works and also other apps already on the taskbar work correctly

I restarted Windows explorer but it didn't solve the issue.

Is there any way to fix this without restarting pc?

Comment: Check for corruption with `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In recent versions of Windows 10](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/18/start-menu-gets-its-own-process-and-a-performance-boost-in-windows-10-19h1/), the Start Menu has been moved out of Windows Explorer and into its own process, `StartMenuExperienceHost.exe`. Try restarting that process instead.

Comment: @Ramhound I could check it now, it's 1803

Comment: So your not using a version that supports this answer.  You really should update.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to killing processes, the quickest “clean” way would probably be to log out and then log back in. Of course, that means you’ll have to save your work.

You can log out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> even when the start menu is broken.

Comment: Yes, that probably would help, unfortunately it's not much quicker than reboot and still I'd loose my open apps.